# Fixing JAIR style

Tags: hyperref, errors, apa-style

According to the [Eigenfactor](http://eigenfactor.org/) ranking of journals, the [Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research](http://www.jair.org/) (JAIR) is [a leading open-access journal in AI](http://www.eigenfactor.org/rankings.php?bsearch=artificial%20intelligence&searchby=journal&orderby=eigenfactor).  Unfortunately, the [JAIR style files](http://www.jair.org/JAIRAuthorKit.zip) are twenty years old and break horribly when trying to use `hyperref`.  This particular error seems due to the shipped `theapa` styles which `jair.sty` depends on.

I have spent several hours trying to understand and fix the errors, but this seems to require a higher skill level of LaTeX hacking than I have attained.  To replicate the problem, add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the preamble of the provided `sample.tex` input file, then run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX; the next and final run of LaTeX (to resolve the dangling references) then fails with

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a   
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...  
l.65 ...d graph partitioning problems \cite{papad}  
                                                  .
```

at the very first place in the file where `\cite{}` is used.  Note that if `hyperref` is *not* used, then these errors go away; packages like `url` or `tikz` work fine.  If the bibliography commands are removed, then the error also goes away.  A similar error occurs when changing `\bibliographystyle{theapa}` to standard bibliography styles, such as `short`:

```
! Use of \@year@ doesn't match its definition.
\Y@papad ->\@year@ J
                    PY
l.65 ...d graph partitioning problems \cite{papad}
                                                  .
```

Finally, if one removes the `\usepackage{theapa}` from the document preamble, then the problem goes away (except that `\shortcite{}` and other `theapa` macros are now undefined).  I have even tried to use a different version of `theapa.sty` from the custom one that is shipped with `jair.sty` but this seems to give the same problems.

Does anyone have ideas about what to change in the `jair.sty` style file to avoid this problem?  If we can track down the issue then I would be happy to work on a patch to submit to JAIR.  It would be nice to help this volunteer-run journal to support bibliographies with internal links and hyperlinks to articles in the bibliography, as publishers like Elsevier do.

Comment: Imho it isn't worth to patch `theapa`. Better switch to biblatex and reimplement the bibliography styles and commands with its tools. Beside solving the hyperref issues it will also give you better unicode/utf8 support (with biber).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Moving to Biblatex would be awesome, but decrease the odds of an update being accepted. It's still new, and there are an awful lot of old TeX distributions out there. If both were made available...

Comment: Have you tried loading the `natbib` package as well? It might provide just enough functionality to keep `hyperref` from blowing up.

Comment: Such old TeX-system will also contain quite old hyperref version. Do you want to support them too? Btw: you could also try either to load theapa after hyperref or to use the trick mentioned in readme.pdf to get the cite package to work. But both will disable links for cite commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Look at this from the perspective of a volunteer-run journal. Adding new technologies that, let's face it, a good fraction of authors will not have installed immediately hurts you. These backwards authors can't compile their work, and will a) ask for help (volunteer run remember) and/or b) take their manuscript somewhere else. It's fine to update packages and technologies, but there *must* be a latency.

Comment: @Mark: There are enough possibilities to allow users to use new packages and features without breaking compability for older systems. You could e.g. write a "theapa2.sty". Or enable biblatex through an option. Or ... I'm not saying you should drop support for older systems but I don't think that it is sensible to invest a lot work to enable modern features like links for people who use them. If someone wants to use an old system he should also accept the restrictions of this system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That seems to be very reasonable. I like it!

Comment: Can I stop using EPS now? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that

`\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}`

is enough to stop `hyperref` and the JAIR styles from stomping on each other.  This is even with JAIR's BibTeX style file modified by [`urlbst`](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/urlbst/) to support DOI fields and inline hyperlinked URLs.

Option `implicit=false` prevents the `hyperref` package from redefining some LaTeX internals, according to the documentation.  With `implicit=false` the hyperlinks within the document also seem to be omitted, but that is not so important for me.

Comment: Hello. I have a similar problem but with using `biblatex-apa` package instead of theapa.sty (my document has nothing to do with JAIR and doesn't uses its style files). I tried to change the order I call `biblatex` and `hyperref`, and also tried to use `implicit=false`, but the problem remains. I know this is not the proper way for asking this, but, please, could you tell me what els could I try?? This is awful. Even if I don't call `hyperref`, I get the same error (`Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition`).

Answer (score 6):

You can get a bit of the functionality you want by inserting the `hyperref` package as shown in the minimal below (these settings worked with the sample2e.tex example file in the JAIR folder).

```
\documentclass[jair,twoside,11pt,theapa]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    bookmarks=false,    % show bookmarks bar?
    pdftitle={TeX and friends hackers manual},    % title
    pdfauthor={Yiannis Lazarides},                     % author
    pdfsubject={TeX and LaTeX},                        % subject of the document
    pdfkeywords={TeX, LaTeX, graphics, images}, % list of keywords
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,       % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,       % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,        % color of file links
    urlcolor=purple,        % color of external links
    linktoc=page            % only page is linked
}
\usepackage{jair, theapa, rawfonts}

\jairheading{1}{1993}{1-15}{6/91}{9/91}
\ShortHeadings{Minimizing Conflicts: A Heuristic Repair Method}
{Minton, Philips, Johnston, \& Laird}
\firstpageno{25}

\begin{document}
\section{One}\label{sec:one}
\section{Three}
  In Section \ref{sec:one}, we referenced \ldots
\section{Four}
  Some more text.
\end{document}
```

However, as you correctly pointed out the class files are in need of an overhaul for screen viewing. In print the style offers an outstanding style for a journal article. I would suggest the following approach.

1. Copy the basic `.cls` into a `.dtx` file so that you can document the changes.
2. Aim for immediate functionality first without any bibliography and citations.
3. Declare an option 'oldclass' or similar to switch on the old style files for backward compatibility.
4. Ensure everything works without any errors up to this point.
5. Upgrade the class to BiblateX, so that the class will survive another possibly 20 years, which by that time AI would have advanced enough to take over from that point onward!

The advantage of this approach, you will ensure backwards compatibility and you can make incremental improvements in a better way. Budget 1-2 weeks full time work, if you fairly well versed with LaTeX.

Comment: When I add hyperref with these options to the sample file, the first run of pdflatex succeeds, but the second run (when the citation names are actually inserted into the document) fails.  So this doesn't look like a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have suffered the same compatibility problems when writing a JAIR article. It turns out that `theapa` can be made mostly compatible with `hyperref` with a little effort in your preamble:

- The loading order is important: first `hyperref`, then `refstyle` (or your cross reference package of choice, which may require to be loaded *before* `hyperref`), and last `jair` and `theapa`. In this way, we can enable `hyperref` support for hyperlinks, hyperlinked cross references, bookmarks, PDF attributes and PDF layout:

```
%use this command unless it is already invoked earlier in the preamble
\makeatletter

\usepackage[implicit=true,unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={my title},
  pdfauthor={my name},
  pdfsubject={my subject},
  pdfkeywords={my keywords},
  %all links are black to preserve the appearance of a printed paper
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=black,
  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
  pdfnewwindow=true,
}

\usepackage{refstyle}

%we also use the package rawfonts because this this is copied verbatim
%from the JAIR author kit (http://www.jair.org)
\usepackage{jair, theapa, rawfonts}
```

- After loading these packages, we still have not hyperlink support for the citations. We have to redefine an internal command from `theapa`, and define new commands equivalent to the citation commands of `theapa`:

```
%load this package unless you have loaded it earlier
\usepackage{ifpdf}

%only the pdflatex driver can handle hyperlinks that break across lines
%(as citations often do) so we define them only when using pdflatex
\ifpdf

  %we add hyperref support with the commands \hyper@natanchorstart and \hyper@natanchorend
  \def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\def\BBA{\BBAA}\item[\hyper@natanchorstart{#2}\@biblabel{#1}\hyper@natanchorend]\if@filesw
        { \def\BBA{\string\BBA}%
          \def\protect##1{\string ##1\space}\immediate
          \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}%
    \def\BBA{\BBAA}}\fi\ignorespaces}

  %load this package unless you have loaded it earlier
  \usepackage{ifthen}

  %new citation commands. Add more as needed, using the existing ones as templates
  %hyperref support is added by using the commands \hyper@natlinkstart and \hyper@natlinkend
  \newcommand{\mshortcite}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\shortcite{#2}}{\shortcite[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mshortciteA}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\shortciteA{#2}}{\shortciteA[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mfullciteA}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\fullciteA{#2}}{\fullciteA[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mshortciteR}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\shortciteR{#2}}{\shortciteR[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mciteyear}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\citeyear{#2}}{\citeyear[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mciteyearR}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\citeyearR{#2}}{\citeyearR[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mshortciteS}[2][]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#2}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\shortciteS{#2}}{\shortciteS[#1]{#2}}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mshortciteauthor}[1]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#1}\shortciteauthor{#1}\hyper@natlinkend}
  \newcommand{\mfullciteauthor}[1]{\hyper@natlinkstart{#1}\fullciteauthor{#1}\hyper@natlinkend}

\else

  %default definitions when not using pdflatex
  \let\mcite\shortcite
  \let\mcitea\shortciteA
  \let\mcitear\fullciteA
  \let\mciter\shortciteR
  \let\mciteyear\citeyear
  \let\mciteyearr\citeyearR
  \let\mcites\shortciteS
  \let\mciteauthor\shortciteauthor
  \let\mciteauthorr\fullciteauthor
  \let\mcitetable\mciter

\fi

%use this command unless it is already invoked later in the preamble
\makeatother
```

And that's it!

Using these code snippets in your preamble will enable almost full `hyperref` support in your JAIR articles. Beware that some `theapa` functionality is missing in the new citation commands, such as optional arguments in angle brackets, or citing more than one reference with a single citation command.

If you just want to use `theapa` without `jair`, just substitute

```
\usepackage{jair, theapa, rawfonts}
```

by

```
\usepackage{theapa}
```

**UPDATE:** It has been brought to my attention that this solution only worked with `pdflatex`, but  not for producing DVI->PS, because the DVI driver is unable to handle links in citations that break across lines. The solution is to enable the new citation commands only for `pdflatex` using `ifpdf`. The code has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when using `apacite` package and `hyperref` package simultaneously. With the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a   
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...  
l.65 ...d graph partitioning problems \cite{xxxx}
```

It turned out that I had put `\usepackage{apacite}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}`. I just moved `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\usepackage{apacite}` and everything works for me now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.